# How can I include fieldset in Zend Form XML

Tags: xml, zend-framework, zend-form

I would like to include some form elements in a fieldset.
How can I do this in a Zend Form XML ?

My XML file:

```
<elements>
        <nom>
            <type>text</type>
            <options>
                <label>Nom, Prénom</label>
                <width>100</width>
                <required>true</required>
             </options>
        </nom>

       <email>
            <type>text</type>
            <options>
                <label>Email</label>
                <description>Votre email</description>
                <width>100</width>
                <validators>
                    <email>
                        <validator>EmailAddress</validator>
                    </email>
                </validators>
            </options>
        </email>

        <message>
            <type>textarea</type>
            <options>
                <label>Message</label>
                <cols>20</cols>
                <rows>5</rows>
                <required>true</required>
            </options>
        </message>      
</elements>
```

So first, is it possible to create fieldset in Zend Form XML ?
And if it's possible, how to put some of this elements in ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying fieldsets/subforms is apparently not possible yet. See

- http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5613

for possible workarounds.